# What jqueryUI plugin is recommended for folders -files structure GUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I want to build a folders-files GUI.

How can I use jquery.UI for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

jsTree is what I use for things like that.

http://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 0):

This may be seen as a "what's your favorite" question, but I'll answer: I personally like http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/ from abeauttifulsite.com. (GPL and MIT licensed)

Answer (score 0):

**No,** jQuery UI has a planned tree structure (IIRC), but file trees are not a current feature. There are any number of other plugins, some which may even use jQuery UI's widget factory.